# Is it possible to adjust the screen brightness from a Service?

Tags: android

I don't want to create a dummy activity or use activities at all. Can it be done?

I do know that you're apk does require a default activity. My application uses that activity to spawn an unbound service and then closes itself. In other words I will not have access to an activity instance in my code.

Comment: It's generally expected on Stack Overflow that anyone asking a question will have tried something first *BEFORE* asking a question. As for not wanting to use activities at all, you'll need at least one `Activity` otherwise you'll never be able to start your `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `Service` does not have a UI you cannot change the screen brightness like you would in an `Activity`. That being said, you should be able to change the brightness by modifying the `SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS` setting; more information here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS

Keep in mind that any `Service` must be started by an `Activity` so you will, at minimum, have to have an `Activity` that does nothing but launch your `Service`.